# PostgreSQL: non-GUI monitoring

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I've read a lot about PostgreSQL monitoring through GUI tools but that doesn't match our modus operandi: shell or Perl scripts tied to SCCS for change-control/auditing, run via cron or interactively.  We tend to prefer the command line over point-and-click.

The closest I've found is pg_top, which I'm working on installing (grumble grumble), and check_postgres.pl, which is a back-end to data collection for Nagios and MRTG.  Although the graph presentation is pretty, it's not our approach... but the Perl itself appears quite useful (so far).

Are there other non-GUI tools out there I may be missing?  Although I could write what's needed, I'd hate to reinvent wheels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the built-in monitoring views?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html 
http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/107.php

Edit:

There is also pgStatspack for performance monitoring:
http://pgfoundry.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=1758

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the built-ins and of the offerings in $PHOME/share/contrib.  pgStatspack is new to me -- thanks.